# Elasticsearch - inconsistent num of document between _cat/indices and <index>/_search

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is what I got from the two URLs

http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v

```
health status index          pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
green  open   myindex        5   1         40            0    263.4kb        131.7kb
```

http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search

```
hits: {total: 10, max_score: 1, hits: [...]}
```

hits.total=10 returned from the second URL is expected, but why docs.count = 40 returned the first URL is different? Thanks!

Comment: If you add an example document, we will probably see three nested fields in there like Michael Stockerl says. So each document counts as 4 for `_/cat/indices` API. Read the notes at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html#cat-indices

Answer (score 2):

If you stored documents with type *nested* in the index, the difference in document is most likely because of that.

Each nested document is stored as separate hidden document within Elasticsearch to be able to keep relationships within these nested documents.
For more information, it is well documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html)

Thus, as it is hidden, you can not find it via the search api and only get the "main" documents as results.

Moreover, there is an [issue on github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17319) which should clarify the difference between the two counts.

Answer (score 0):

One option is that you have deleted docs: documents are immutable in ES so any modification (including delete) will create a new copy of the doc with a new version-number.

The call to `_cat/indices?v` returns a count of all the docs including the deleted ones, though you can't access them through `_search`

Comment: I did not delete any document. the symptom was very easy to reproduce. I posted 10 documents to a new index, myindex, then I went to check the url, http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v, it returned docs.count=40. I understand that it could be inconsistent but would like know what ES does underneath.